# Fourier transform of $t^n\exp(-\alpha\vert t\vert)$ $(n\geq0)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I met this Fourier transformation when dealing with bath properties in physics. I would appreciate any clue on this.

Comment: First figure out what the transform is when $n=0$ that is a straightforward integral you should be able to do.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, for $n=0$ it is just an integral of exponential function as shown in [Fourier_Transformation_of_$\exp(-a\vert t\vert)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928318/fourier-transformation-of-e-ax). For $n>0$ it shows in a Gamma-function form, where I am confused about how to deal the imaginary part in the exponential.

Comment: What about taking derivatives (w.r.t. the FT variable)?

Comment: @metamorphy Good point! I have got the general formula. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank @metamorphy for his suggestion. This Fourier transformation can be calculated recursively.

We first split the total integral into two parts
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt\ t^n \exp(-\alpha\vert t\vert-i\omega t)= \int_{0}^{\infty} dt\ t^n \exp(-\alpha t-i\omega t) + \int_{-\infty}^{0} dt\ t^n \exp(\alpha t-i\omega t).$$ Denote the first part as $I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} dt\ t^n \exp(-\alpha t-i\omega t)$ and then take derivative with respect to $\omega$,  one can obatin
$$I_{n+1}=i\frac{\partial I_n}{\partial \omega}.$$
Starting from $I_0=\frac{1}{\alpha+i\omega}$, the recursive relation yields
$$I_n=\frac{n!}{(\alpha+i\omega)^{n+1}}.$$
The same procedure can be done for the second part. The final result reads
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt\ t^n \exp(-\alpha\vert t\vert-i\omega t)=\frac{n!}{(\alpha+i\omega)^{n+1}}+\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(\alpha-i\omega)^{n+1}}\quad n\in \mathbb{N}$$

Answer (score 0):

Fourier Transform of double decaying exponential with t^n polynomial growth Fourier Transform Pair

```
  x(t)                         X(j ω)

exp(-α|t|)                    2α/(α^2+ ω^2)

t^n x(t)                      j^n (d^n/dω^n) (X(jw))
__________________________________________________
```

n*************t^n x(t)***********************Xn(j ω)

0    *************   x(t)**********************2α/(ω^2+α^2)

1*******    *****   t x(t)*******************-j4ωα/(ω^2+α^2)^2

2**********          t^2 x(t)*****************(-16ω^2α)/((ω^2+α^2)^3

n********** t^n x(t)**********     (i^n)n!C(ω^n)α /((ω^2+α^2)^(n+1)

All you need for the general solution is to determine constant C.

Hint: look at the pattern generated by this table, can you see a trend is developing?

---

Comment: Good heavens.... [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), **please.**

Comment: Bear with me, I am new to Mathjax.  At least I can post it in an hour.  If I use Mathjax, it may take me a day or longer. 

See the results  got for using Mathjax   after 1-day  try and error .  It is still not perfect, bur readable.  Can you fix the integral formula for me in this post? I tried all day.  Never succeed! 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142084/determine-a-formula-for-a-given-bn-in-a-fourier-representation/4142191#4142191

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142084/determine-a-formula-for-a-given-bn-in-a-fourier-representation/4142191#4142191